# Is there TRIM support in OS X 10.6.9 for PowerPC?

Tags: macos, ssd, powerpc, powerbook

A friend of mine has a PowerBook running 10.6.9. To give it another lease of life, he'd like to install an SSD. Question is: does OS X on PPC have TRIM support?

Comment: Your friend gave you a wrong information. Snow Leopard is not PPC compatible.

Comment: Hm. You're right!

Comment: Please clarify the version number – there was no Mac OS X 10.6.9. 10.4.9, maybe? The *OS X* column at http://opensource.apple.com/ is a handy reminder of the 10.4.x transition from PowerPC to Intel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few searches tell me that there isn't good SSD support for power pc macs.

This seems to be mostly a SATA III compatibility issue. TRIM support seems to have been introduced in 10.6.8 but only for Apple-supplied drives. Since Apple was producing Intel-based systems by that point, that is where they focused the support.

There are blog posts where people have talked about specific drives working in G5 and G4 macs but this is notably without TRIM.

OWC has some posts about TRIM and how it isn't for everyone.

The important question is, why do you need TRIM?

Comment: From the *First appearance …* observation at http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/120271/8546 I initially guessed that support began with Mac OS X 10.8.1. So maybe Apple support for TRIM began late in Snow Leopard … then open sourcing of the code in Mountain Lion.

Comment: It is my understanding that Lion was the first release with true TRIM support. The Snow Leopard support was limited to Apple-supplied drives. I am guessing that this is because they off loaded TRIM support to firmware that they added to specific drives.